# Tailwind Elements components don't get triggered in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install, tailwind-css

I tried to add [Tailwind Elements](https://tailwind-elements.com) to my Angular project to be able to use some of their components (eg: [Date picker](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/datepicker/)).

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I have some elements working (like the date picker field is transformed to a kinda material looking floating input). But when I click on it, my **date picker calendar isn't fired**.

I followed the steps given in the NPM [installation guide](https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/) :
1- I have Node installed and TailwindCss in my project
2- Installed Tailwind Elements via npm
3-  Added the needed code in my tailwind.config.ts file :
4- I'm **kinda stuck on point 4 though**... They ask to add in the index.html file this script call :

```js
<script src="./TW-ELEMENTS-PATH/dist/js/index.min.js"></script>
```

But I can't really do that in an Angular project (I tried but it doesn't work).
I tried as well to add this index.min.js file in my project and declare it in my angular.json file on the "scripts" section (doesn't work either).
I tried as well to call this script via a CDN (doesn't work).

So if someone has an idea to make Tailwind Elements work in an Angular project, I'll take any hint ;)

### Edit

Well, in fact I managed to make Tailwind Elements work in my Angular project by adding this in my angular.json file :

```json
"styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
   "node_modules/tw-elements/dist/src/scss/index.scss"
],
"scripts": [
   "src/assets/tailwind-elements.js",
   "node_modules/tw-elements/dist/js/index.min.js"
]
```

#### Last problem though

In fact the problem didn't really come from my install. I tried other components and it seems to work fine. This freaking DatePicker refuses to get triggered though... So if an idea comes to your mind...

Comment: I'm having a similarly difficult time finding an example of an angular application working using tw-elements.  Your note about the angular.json file did get me farther, but all of my components are acting oddly.  For example, I'll copy example code from https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/accordion/ and it will toggle properly but the visibility of the accordion-body is collapsed when it shouldn't be.. etc